# Rails schema dump is putting string in for postgres point.. How do I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, migration

I have a POINT defined in my migrations... when I run the migrations I get a POINT in my database.. Perfect!!  Just exactly what I asked for.

But.. What I see in schema.rb is t.string?   This messes up my CI system, because it builds the database based on the schema.rb.
Now my co-worker wants to change the type in the database to array, because it would be easy.  I find that leaves a stink in my code.

Q: How do I make the schema.rb file show the column as a point?

---

For completeness
/20141120 ... .rb

```
class AddHeaderToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :header_image_centre, :point
  end
end
```

/schema.rb

```
t.string   "header_image_centre",                 limit: nil
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in Rails 4.2